# Replace string dynamically

Tags: php, regex, string, match

How can I remove this string:

```
class="size-full wp-image-1561 "
```

from this string:

`class="size-full wp-image-1561 " alt="Class-A warehouse facility developed by Panattoni Europe in Germany for Rudolph Logistik Gruppe." src="http://europe-re.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Class-A-warehouse-facility-developed-by-Panattoni-Europe-in-Germany-for-Rudolph-Logistik-Gruppe.jpg"`

Consider that the class changes every record. How can I do it dynamically?
Something like `"remove class="(whatever is inside here)"` from the full string.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a regex is the only means you have at hand, you can match

```
\bclass="[^"]*"\s*
```

The, replace with an empty string. `\b` makes sure we are matching `class`, not `subclass`.

With `[^"]*`, we can match 0 or more characters other than `"`.

With `\s*`, we can trim the string automatically.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA9zS3/3)

However, if you deal with PHP, you'd better be using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Something similar to

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="res">Some text inside DIV
<img
class="size-full wp-image-1561 "
alt="Class-A warehouse facility developed by Panattoni Europe in Germany for Rudolph Logistik Gruppe."
src="http://europe-re.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Gruppe.jpg">
<img
alt="Class-A warehouse facility developed by Panattoni Europe in Germany for Rudolph Logistik Gruppe."
src="http://europe-re.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Gruppe.jpg">
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$imgs = array();
foreach($images as $img) {
    if ($img->attributes->getNamedItem("class") != null) {
        $imgs[] = $img;
    }
}
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
}

$str = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $str;
```

Output of the [sample IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qRbRTJ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div id="res">Some text inside DIV
<img alt="Class-A warehouse facility developed by Panattoni Europe in Germany for Rudolph Logistik Gruppe." src="http://europe-re.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Gruppe.jpg"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
class\s*=\s*".*?"\s*
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tH3nP2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If class changes for every record but format remains the same I would go for a faster solution. Just check the position of second '"' and go for a substring:

```
substr($str, 8+strpos(substr($str,7), '"'))
```

If the format changes, then have a look at preg_replace()